# Cadastro wordpress letra maiuscula

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Como eu impeço que clientes se cadastrarem no wordpress com e-mail com letra maiúscula? Alguma função sem plugin?

Comment: Stephanie entende. Parece que mesmo o Caractere aparecendo em minúsculo dentro do input quando vai pro banco ele continua como maiúsculo... Como não respondeu a pergunta preferi apagar a resposta ok. Parece que vc vai ter que converter a string com JS para minúsculo antes de enviar pro banco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.email').keyup(function() {

    $(this).val(function(i, val) {
           return val.toLowerCase();
    });

    });
});
</script>

<input type="text" class="email">
```

Espero que ajude!

Answer (score 1):

Olá, se estiver utilizando o formulário padrão de registro do Wordpress, pode utilizar o filtro `user_registration_email`. O mesmo pode ser adicionado no `functions.php` do seu tema ou em um plugin.

```
function wpes_lowercase_register_email($user_email)
{
    return strtolower($user_email);
}

add_filter('user_registration_email', 'wpes_lowercase_register_email');
```